Using Pandas, make a new column from the string slice of another column -- getting NAN
I want to create a new column from an extracting Data Frame (DF) column.
All my testing indicates the values I am using are correct and should produce a level1 value vs NAN.
Help!
CODE SNIPPET:
import pandas as pd
string = df['currentagentsnapshot']
start  = string.str.find('agent-group') + 55
stop   = string.str.find('}, level2=')
df['start']  = string.str.find('agent-group') + 55
df['stop']   = string.str.find('}, level2=')
df['level1'] = string.str[df['start']:df['stop']]
print(df.head())

SAMPLE OUTPUT OF KEY FIELDS:



awsaccountid
start
stop
level1




992974280925
410
414
NaN


992974280925
410
414
NaN


992974280925
410
414
NaN


992974280925
408
412
NaN


992974280925
408
412
NaN



Note:  df['currentagentsnapshot'] is a LARGE text string.  As long as start and stop are both numbers -- and stop > start -- I would expect string.str[df['start']:df['stop']] to produce the expected result.
Running the above script produces NAN instead of the expected string value.
All the examples I have checked on the WEB reference constant vs calculated values.
When I substitute constant for calculated values in string.str[start : stop] it works.

Please provide a [mre] of the input. It's difficult to debug without a clear example.

data = { 'currentagent': [ "some large text with agent-group info and }, level2=more text", "another example with agent-group data here and }, level2=continued", "yet another string agent-group details and }, level2=info", "text with agent-group data and }, level2=more", "last example of agent-group information and }, level2=content" ] } df = pd.DataFrame(data)
def extract_level1(row): start = row['currentagent'].find('agent-group') + 55 stop = row['currentagent'].find('}, level2=') if start != -1 and stop != -1 and stop > start: return row['currentagentsnapshot'][start:stop] else: return None
df['level1'] = df.apply(extract_level1, axis=1)
print(df)

I modified the data frame input and was able to get it to work.  Is there a reason why a function is needed for this parsing exercise?   My original script was creating correct values for start and stop but when applied as [start:stop] these values did not appear to be recognized as integer values.   Thanks!!!

I hope it can help you.
With your data, create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Later, you can define a new function to use the method apply from Pandas, it can iterate in the specified column, and you define in the function what to do with each row:
def extract_level1(row):
    """
    Define a function to extract the substring based on dynamic start and stop
    
    Args: row-A row from a dataframe with the string

    Return: string: A string between the start and the stop
    """
    start = row.find('agent-group') + 55
    stop = row.find('}, level2=')
    if start < stop and start >= 0 and stop >= 0:
        return row[start:stop]
    else:
        return None

# Apply the function to the 'currentagentsnapshot' column
df['level1'] = df['currentagentsnapshot'].apply(extract_level1)

# Display the DataFrame with the new column
print(df.head())

Also, I think, you can use the method pd.Series.str.contains(str, regex=True) that uses regex and returns a bool, later you can filter this.
